# Get SharePoint list item attachment names in multiline text field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, out-of-the-box

I want to get SharePoint list item attachment names in a multiline text field.

When I click on new item in the list and attach some attachments and click on save I want all the attachment names to be displayed on the multiline text field say "My attachments" in the list. Can I do with the calculated column/designer workflow.
We are not supposed to use event receiver.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with workflows and calculated columns but I got no good results.

I will suggest you to follow this post http://amitphule.blogspot.be/2012/04/display-item-attachments-in-sharepoint.html as using SharePoint Designer and modifyng the XSLT view.